# Etoken как флешка

Tags: ubuntu

Есть старый Etoken, можно ли его превратить в обычную флешку? Использую ОСь Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, если он eToken NG-FLASH у других флеша нету

Comment: есть etoken gt, но ведь в нём всё равно есть объем памяти. Вопрос как его использовать?

Comment: Ну не знаю, как можно использовать 8 Kb защищенной памяти. Наверное только по прямому назначению, как eToken.

Comment: А HASP ключи, они уже не содержат памяти?

Comment: http://www.haspkey.ru/